# Share image to Google+ in Android app?

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm working on a project that needs share image from my app to Google+.
But when find out some samples relating to my problems, they requires installed Google+ from Google Play for sharing anything.
So the question is : How can I share from my app without installing any extra app? Or install Google+ from Google Play is the only way to solve my problem?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Yes you do require google plus isntalled in the device to share..

Comment: Check if g+ is installed `errorCode = GooglePlusUtil.checkGooglePlusApp(this); If (errorCode  == GooglePlusUtil.SUCCESS)` then share image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope May this help you...

```
File tmpFile = new File("/path/to/image");
 final String photoUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
         getContentResolver(), tmpFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, null);

 Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
         .setText("Hello from Google+!")
         .setType("image/jpeg")
         .setStream(Uri.parse(photoUri))
         .getIntent()
         .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
```

The Google+ app only supports content:// URIs. You will need to use the `MediaStore` API for this...

Comment: @BhavinNattar : I tried to share GIF but It only displayed the first frame. How can I share Animated GIF?

Comment: @EastBK: Buddy try to do the same but change these line in your code `.setType("image/gif")` before that..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can always take a look at the [web api](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) if they provide you with means to authenticate your user and upload posts with an image.

I assume however, that simply using the app itself will save you a lot of hassle.